# REACT-How can I include ly button in my gray bar with tailwindcss?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to include my `-` button in my gray bar. As you can see in the picture, my blue button exceeds the gray bar

```
export default function App() {
...
return (
<div className="text-md font-bold">
                            Invitee {i + 1}
                            <span className="float-right ">
                                {!!i && (
                                    <Button className="rounded-md float-right mt-4" primary onClick={() => removeInvitee(Id)}>
                                        -
                                    </Button>
                                )}
                            </span>
...
)
```

Comment: Are there any other CSS rules that are being applied in that button? Because these classes do not seem to be the issue.

Comment: Hi, yes I've edited my issue

Comment: It looks like the classes that deal with padding cause the button's size to grow and overflow the `div`. Try removing the classes that affect the vertical padding.

Comment: I've removed all the padding but still not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flexbox properties to make the design you want. I had created the very similar example below , please add your functions here and replace `class` with `className`.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="container mx-auto py-4">
<div class="bg-gray-200 text-md flex items-center justify-between rounded-r-md">
  <div class=" font-bold  text-gray-500 ml-4" >Invitee 2</div>
  <div class="">
    <Button primary class="rounded-md bg-black text-white py-2 px-4" onclick="removeInvitee(pId)">
        -
    </Button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Is it normal that it works fine for all the Invitee>1. Because for Invitee1 the height of my gray bar is not the same as Invitee2 or Invitee3. See [here](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/invitee1.png) please